# How to resolve xp_cmdshell access denied error?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I tried to get images names from my folder with exec XP_CMDSHELL 'dir /B C:\Users\pc\Desktop\images\images2\items*.jpg';

Output is above

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQ7o3.png)

I had tried  solutions in this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-cmdshell-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

```
sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell',1 
reconfigure with override

GRANT EXECUTE ON xp_cmdshell TO [user]

EXEC sp_xp_cmdshell_proxy_account 'user', 'password'

create credential ##xp_cmdshell_proxy_account## with identity = 'user', secret = 'password
```

'

I wanna open folder names in my sql server and stored in a custom table.

Comment: From a security point of view it's generally a bad idea to enable `xp_cmdshell`. Your access denied error is because the Windows account that the SQL Server service is running under doesn't have file system access to your `C:\Users\pc\Desktop\images\images2` folder and/or the files within it.

Comment: Nor should the SQL Server Service account have access to a different user's documents. As for your point, @AlwaysLearning, about *"it's generally a bad idea to enable"* this is more of a "nonsense point". To use `xp_cmdshell` you need to be a `sysadmin`, and if someone malicious has access to a `syadmin` account it's trivial for them to en able `xp_cmdshell`. Turning it off is about a 10ms bump in the road for them.